# Prove rational nums

Tags: proof-writing, rational-numbers

For all real number x : R(x) -> there exist two integers k, l such that x = k/l.

(i.e. x is a rational number)

**Prove/Disprove:**
For all real number x : R(x) -> R(x+1)

**My answer:**

Let x be a real number.

Assume R(x).

Then R(x+1) = R(x) + R(1) # R(x) is rational and R(1) is rational because 1/1 = 1

Is that correct and complete? What is the more formal way of showing this proof?

Comment: $R(x+1)\neq R(x)+R(1)$ because $R$ is a predicate: a function that returns a truth value.

Comment: The definition of "rational" was that stuff about integers k and l? How come that didn't show up in your proof? If you're proving something about rational numbers, don't you think the meaning of "rational" should come up somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is rational, then $x = a/b$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $b \in \mathbb{Z}^*$.

$x+1 = \frac{a}{b} + 1 = \frac{a+b}{b}$. As $a+b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x+1$ is also rational.

Comment: Question: what does the * after the Z mean?

Comment: How do you know that $a+b\in\mathbb Z$? If it's because it's the sum of 2 integers, that's what we're trying to prove?

Comment: @AdamHrankowski I think we have to prove that x+1 is rational, not that the sum of two integers is an integer. In order to prove that the integers are closed under addition, I guess we would need to go from the construction of the set of integers, which would need to go from the construction of the set of naturals, which depends on some axioms, like Peano axioms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms).

Comment: What I was thinking was that if we *assume* that the sum of two integers is rational, then when we know that $x+1$ is rational, being the itself the sum of two integers. I was working on the same proof myself when this occurred to me.

Comment: But we are not assuming that the sum of two integers is rational. We are assuming that the sum of two integers is integer.

Answer (score 2):

The set of all rationals with the usual addition and multiplication is a field; the number $1$ is rational; therefore, for every rational $x$ the number $x+1$ is again rational.

Comment: Are the rationals a field because they are closed under addition, or are they closed under addition because they are a field? I thought of a similar proof myself, but I wasn't sure if it was circular reasoning. I know they are a field *because* I know they are closed under addition.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p/q$ be a rational, $q\neq0$. Then $p/q+1=(p+q)/q$ which is again a quotient of two integers, hence rational.

Answer (score 0):

> For all real number x : R(x) <-> there exist two integers k, l such that x = k/l.

Assuming $R(x)$ is true, then there exists integers $k, l$ such that $x=k/l$.    If so then $(x+1) = (k+l)/l$.   Now $(k+l)$ will be an integer, which means that there exists two integers $(k+l)$ and $l$ such that $(x+1)$ is their quotient.   That is $R(x+1)$.

$$\therefore R(x)\to R(x+1)$$

$\Box$